# Erro na importação de XML

Tags: php, xml

Na importação de arquivo XML de nota fiscal eletronica o php apresenta o seguinte erro:

Warning: Illegal string offset 'codigo' in C:\xampp\htdocs\xmlparser\saida\importNFe_saida.php on line 127

Abaixo código PHP

```
<?php

Linha

121   // Tag det dos itens unitarios:
121    $det=$doc->getElementsByTagName('det');
122    $itens="";
123    for ($i = 0; $i < $det->length; $i++) {
124    $item=$det->item($i);
125    $s="";
126    $s['codigo']=tagValue($item,"cProd");
127    $s['ean']=tagValue($item,"cEAN");
128    $s['nome']=tagValue($item,"xProd");
129    $s['ncm']=tagValue($item,"NCM");
130    $s['cfop']=tagValue($item,"CFOP");
131    $s['unidade']=tagValue($item,"uCom");
132    $s['quantidade']=tagValue($item,"qCom");
133    $s['valor']=tagValue($item,"vUnCom");
134    $s['valorTotal']=tagValue($item,"vProd");
135    $s['icms']=0;
136    $s['ipi']=0;
137    $itens[]=$s;
138        
139    }
140    $dados['itens']=$itens;
141    return($dados);
```

Se alguém puder dar uma luz agradeço.

Answer (score 1):

Esta declarando a variável $s como string, logo após(linha 126) tentando alocar como array

```
125    $s="";
126    $s['codigo']=tagValue($item,"cProd");
```

Declare a variável $s como  array

```
 $s = [];
```